# External display is being overlapped by laptop display. Blue edges

Tags: nvidia, external-monitor, xbmc

I seem to be having difficulty setting Ubuntu up to run on an external monitor for use as a HTPC/XBMC box. No matter what settings I apply I am unable to have the laptop display remain in a position that is not directly overlapping my external display.When it overlaps the desktop quite literally moves and the sides and top when moved towards them have blue bars.  Even when the laptop screen is disabled within NVIDIA's Server Settings the overlap glitch still occurs.

Is there anyway to completely disable the laptops display, such that Ubuntu does not even know it is present? Any other solutions to this problem? The laptop monitor is not used with this setup.

I do have under-scanning enabled within the NVIDIA control screen. It happens after I enter a program the changes the resolution like XBMC.

[image]

please note this screen shot is taken from the external display, the laptop monitor was disabled.

Comment: edited to imgur. http://imgur.com/w3tzYIS